# codeigniter doughnut chartjs displays blank with mysql query data

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, chart.js

I am trying to implement chartjs doughnut with mysql dataset. The code does not have any error but the chart is not displayed on the canvas. Data legends are also not displayed. Any support on the matter will be appreciated.

**model**

The model extract for the project is displayed below:

```
public function getChart3() {
        //current month vehicle make count pie chart query
        $query = $this->db->query( "SELECT ci_vehicle_make.vehicle_make AS 'vehicleMake', count(ci_vehicle_make.vehicle_make) AS 'totalCount'
                FROM ci_parking
                JOIN ci_vehicle ON ci_parking.vehicle_id=ci_vehicle.vehicle_id
                JOIN ci_vehicle_make ON ci_vehicle.vehicle_make_id=ci_vehicle_make.vehicle_make_id
                JOIN ci_vehicle_type ON ci_vehicle.vehicle_type_id=ci_vehicle_type.vehicle_type_id
                WHERE MONTH(ci_parking.parking_entry) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
                AND YEAR(ci_parking.parking_entry) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
                AND ci_parking.is_deleted = 0
                GROUP BY ci_vehicle_make.vehicle_make" );
        $res = $query->result();
        return $res;
    }
```

**controller**

The controller extract for the project is displayed below:

```
public function getChart3() {

        $data = $this->dashboard->getChart3();
        echo( json_encode( $data ) );

    }

    public function index() {
        
        $data[ 'chart3' ] = $this->dashboard->getChart3();

        $this->load->view( 'admin/dashboard/index', $data );

    }
```

**js code**

The javascript code for the project is displayed below:

```
  var pieChartCanvas = $('#pieChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
  var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas)

  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url("/admin/dashboard/getChart3"); ?>",
    method:"GET",
    data:{action:'fetch'},
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data) {

      var vehicle_Make = [];
      var total_Count = [];
      var piecolor = [];
      var len = data.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        vehicle_Make.push(data[i]['vehicleMake']);
        total_Count.push(data[i]['totalCount']);
        randomColor = "#" + randomColor;
        piecolor.push(randomColor);
      }

      //output data
      console.log(vehicle_Make);
      console.log(total_Count);
      console.log(piecolor);

      var PieData = {
        labels: vehicle_Make,
        datasets:[
          {
            data     : total_Count,
            color    : piecolor,
            highlight: piecolor,
            label    : 'Vehicle Make',
          }
        ]
      }

      var pieOptions     = {
        //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
        segmentShowStroke    : true,
        //String - The colour of each segment stroke
        segmentStrokeColor   : '#fff',
        //Number - The width of each segment stroke
        segmentStrokeWidth   : 2,
        //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
        percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
        //Number - Amount of animation steps
        animationSteps       : 100,
        //String - Animation easing effect
        animationEasing      : 'easeOutBounce',
        //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
        animateRotate        : true,
        //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
        animateScale         : false,
        //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
        responsive           : true,
        // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
        maintainAspectRatio  : true,
        //String - A legend template
        legendTemplate       : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
      }
      //Create pie or douhnut chart
      // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
      //pieChart.Pie(PieData, pieOptions)
      pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions)
    }
  });
```

**output**

[image: the output on scree and console]

if I change the last line of code in js to:

```
pieChart.Bar(PieData, pieOptions)
```

The chart is displayed without the random colors:

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to debug this as it is presented, we don't have access to the database and project structure; unless you can make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one can only guess possible problems ... like  do you have a canvas element in the browser inspector, with a correct computed width and height?

Comment: @kikon if I change the last line of the js code to pieChart.Bar(PieData, pieOptions) the canvas displays the bar chart

Comment: Interesting; does the bar chart show the random colors as you expect?

Comment: @kikon I have edited the post including the bar chart that is generated when I edit the pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions) to pieChart.Bar(PieData, pieOptions)

Comment: I suspect that the option for colors should be `backgroundColor: piecolor`; this at least is the way it is in standard `charts.js`, even in [older versions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/samples/other-charts/doughnut.html)

Comment: @kikon I have tried backgroundColor: piecolor still displays an empty canvas

Comment: This needs hands on debugging. You can try to 1) make a working sandbox with (a part of) your code, or 2) take the generated html + javascript page from the browser View Source (if it's not transpiled to something unreadable) and put that in a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the chart.js plugin. I updated the plugin from 1.7 to latest plugin.